# Compose app - Is it possible to programatically get component tree information from RootView/DecorView?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, rootview, textlabel

Our SDK can't be inline with app's code, is there a way to retrieve UI tree info without app developer manually add code snippets to capture the "Component Tree" data without using the Layout Inspector tool?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Radiography on GitHub. Its capable of generating the compose tree in runtime. They do that by accessing non-public methods of the compose tooling library.